# Drawing rectangles in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to draw some rectangles and inside those I want to print the sequence of them using python.For example- If there are 2 rectangles in a figure each of them will contain their number-1,2 respectively. How to do that?

Comment: This is too broad. Please share what you have already tried

Comment: Actually I am not getting any way to write inside a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach in http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0203/:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

patterns = ['-', '+', 'x', 'o', 'O', '.', '*']  # more patterns
fig4 = plt.figure()
 ax4 = fig4.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
 for p in [
    patches.Rectangle(
        (0.05 + (i * 0.13), 0.1),
        0.1,
        0.6,
        hatch=patterns[i],
        fill=False
    ) 
 for i in range(len(patterns))
 ]:
ax4.add_patch(p)
fig4.savefig('rect4.png', dpi=90, bbox_inches='tight')'
```

But here there are hatch patterns. But I want to put just a number at the centre of each rectangle.